# Opening syslog files safely

Tags: linux, syslog, rhel6

I have a syslog server running syslog-ng (soon to be running rsyslog) on RHEL 6 with almost a 1000 hosts logging to it. I want write a script to open each file (read-only and 1 at the time), pull some data from them and close them (probably in Ruby). Will this mess up syslog or cause any other issues? What other pitfalls might I need to be aware of?

My main worry is syslog trying to write data to a file that I have open, even tho I may only have it open for a very short amount of time (maybe less than a second).

possible sudo code:

```
foreach file
  open $file
  grep "search sting" $file
  close $file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the daemon only appends to the file, I think there's no risk. It's deleting/tryncating I would worry about. I think it depends on the configuration of your daemon (not so much on which daemon is used), but I would assume most configs don't actually remove data.

Deleting is typically done with logrotate and other tools. I would look at these tools' configs (e.g. make them run at a different time than the script you're mentioning).